# I wanna show some text on desktop using Mongodb server but it's not working

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am new to learning mongodb when i am requestng api on "/" it's working fine but for the other arguments it's returning 404 error

I tried double slash so it can pile up but nothing is working

This is main index.js

```
import express, { json } from "express";
import { connectDataBase } from "./Helpers/ConnectDb.js";
import Router from "./Routes/Route.js";
const app = express()
const port = 2629

app.use(json())

connectDataBase()

app.use("/test", Router)
```

THis is Router.js

```
import { Router } from "express"
import { getAllUsers, createUser, getUserById, deleteUserById, test } from "../Services/Users.js"

const Route = Router()

Route.post("/test", test)

Route.get("/Users", getAllUsers)
Route.post("/Users", createUser)
Route.get("/Users:id", getUserById)
Route.delete("/Users:id", deleteUserById)

Route.get("/Products", getAllUsers)
Route.get("/Products", getUserById)
Route.post("/Products", createUser)
Route.delete("/Products", deleteUserById)

export default Route
```

THis is the servicers/Users.js

```
import UserModel from "../Models/Users.js"

export const test = async (req, res) => {
    
    res.send("test")
}

export const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
    const users = await UserModel.find().select("-password")
    res.status(200).send({ data: users })
}

export const createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    const user = new UserModel(body)
    await user.save()
    res.status(201).send({ message: "UserModel Added Successfully" })
}

export const getUserById = async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const user = await UserModel.findById(id)
    res.status(200).send({ data: user })
}

export const deleteUserById = async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id
    const user = await UserModel.findByIdAndRemove(id)
    const users = await UserModel.find()
    res.status(200).send({ data: users })
}
```

I am using thunder client for api hits

Comment: What other routes did you try? It looks like everything is under `/test` so the routes are actually `/test/Users`, `/test/Products` etc.